# Reinstall Windows XP on a computer with no Internet connection

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I bought a used Dell Inspiron 6000 that came with Windows 7 installed, but originally had Windows XP on it. Lately, I've been having troubles with it and would like to reinstall XP. The problem is that the wireless internet on it has limited or no connectivity and it has nothing to do with the router, so I can't download any programs to help me with the problems I'm having with it. How do I revert back to the original XP installation?

Comment: Without acess to installation media this can't be done.

Comment: You can't wipe the OS from within using CCleaner while you're booted into it. As stated above, do you have an XP CD and a valid XP key (is the COA sticker still on the PC)?

Comment: Why can't you use a wired connection?

Comment: @jeffreylin_: I approved your edit but just a note - hardware details such as the model of the PC might be unneeded in the title, but you shouldn't remove them altogether. Move them to the body of the question instead.

Comment: @Karan oh, ok. Noted.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use some type of Dell provided utility to burn restore CDs and use those to reinstall XP, if you haven't burned them yet.  Try safe mode if your computer is having issues severe enough to prevent you from burning CDs.  A long time ago OEMs used to give you restore disks, but then switched to making you burn them yourself.

Try pressing F11 to see if there's a recovery partition, but I think those started coming into vogue around the time Vista was released - http://www.geekpolice.net/t7661-dell-system-recovery-partition-hotkey-instructions-dell-pc-restore.

If you had System Restore turned on, you might try going to Start -> Control Panel -> System -> and since it's been a while since I've been on an XP system, I forget where the System Restore options are exactly but look there.  Try restoring to a date before you started having issues.  This isn't equivalent to a reinstallation but may resolve your issue.

If all of the above don't help you, you'd need to get an XP install disk, boot off of it, and run Setup.   If the disk is the same edition as the OEM sticker on the bottom of your laptop indicates, you can enter the indicated key when XP asks for a product key and proceed normally, and even activate normally, no matter where you get the disk.  You might try looking on online auction sites for actual genuine (not burnt or copied) CD media if you can't find one - avoid using a copy downloaded from torrent sites as those may have viruses.

Answer (score 0):

If someone installed Win 7 on the system, they almost certainly overwrote the restore partition.  Is the COA label on the bottom of the device intact?  If so, check around for anyone with the same OS from Dell.  Any Dell OEM CD of same OS will install on your system as long as the BIOS says "Dell".  That said, you may want to consider that Win XP is end-of-life as of April 2014 anyway - no updates, no security patches... may want to consider another OS.